# Decomposition of the multi-controlled gate in tensorflow quantum

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, cirq, tfq

In TensorFlow Quantum 0.5.0, the support for Cirq gates that have arbitrary control via the `gate.controlled_by` function is added.

I would like to know which kind of decomposition method is used for this operation? The current decomposition seems to be efficient and any information related to that is very welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no decomposition being done for controlled operations by default. The library expects whatever simulator it is using to have support for the `controlled_by` operation (by either decomposing it or implementing it directly). In the default C++ simulator TFQ uses [qsim](https://github.com/quantumlib/qsim), controlled gates are implemented via direct application onto the state vector [here](https://github.com/quantumlib/qsim/blob/0b72f1977473b9e2b91377abc00330a1e2c7e7f5/lib/simulator_basic.h#L84)

-Michael